# How to add equal widths constraint using multiplier programmatically in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dynamic, autolayout

This might be a possible duplicate, but the scenario is different.

My ViewController in the storyboard won't have any objects. Everything I created programmatically. I have three views named firstView, secondView and thirdView.

```
UIView *firstView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *secondView = [[UIView alloc] init];
UIView *thirdView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

Constraints for these views are as follows

1. firstView

   ```
   firstView.leading = self.view.leading;
   firstView.trailing = self.view.trailing;
   firstView.top = self.view.top;
   ```
2. secondView

   ```
   secondView.leading = self.view.leading;
   secondView.trailing = self.view.trailing;
   secondView.top = firstView.bottom;
   ```
3. thirdView

   ```
   thirdView.leading = self.view.leading;
   thirdView.trailing = self.view.trailing;
   thirdView.top = secondView.bottom;
   ```

Now I want to set the height of each views as follows.

1. secondView height should be 80% of firstView height
2. thirdView height should be 50% of firstView height.

I know it how to do using Interface Builder, I want to know how can we achieve this programmatically using multiplier.

Comment: try this https://github.com/PureLayout/PureLayout

Comment: what is your view hierarchy ? means which view is added on which view & let me know the you firstView height or relation of firstView height with its superView. So that I would help you.